# How to work with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a simple component `MenuPageComponent` in my app:

```
...
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MenuPageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private menuService = inject(MenuService); 
  menu: Menu[] = [];
  categories = [
    {id: 1,name: "Food"},
    {id: 2,name: "Bar"}
  ]

 
  // From API 
  constructor() {
    this.menuService.fetch().pipe(
      takeUntilDestroyed()
    ).subscribe(
      response => this.menu = response
    )
  }  
   // Filter - split data by category = bar & food
   getByCategory(categoryId: number) : Menu[] {
    return this.menu.filter((result) => {
      return result.category === categoryId;
    })
  }
```

with a html template (mat-tab):

[image]

```
 <mat-tab-group color="accent">
  @for (category of categories; track category.id) {
    <mat-tab>
      <ng-template mat-tab-label>{{ category.name }}</ng-template>
  
   @for (menuItem of getByCategory(category.id); track menuItem.id) {

      <ng-container>
          <div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="title">{{ menuItem.name }}</div>
              <div class="space"></div>
              <div class="price">{{ menuItem.price }}₽</div>
            </div>
            <p class="description">{{ menuItem.description }}</p>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
   }

    </mat-tab>
  }
</mat-tab-group>
```

When I visit the page for the first time, everything works fine. When I switch to the "Bar" tab, everything is fine there too. But when I go back to the Food tab, the data disappears.

[image]
[image]

When i  remove `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` it works fine.
Can i use "OnPush" on this component? (or is this completely unnecessary?)

Comment: Hmmm to be honest I cannon see catch any change detection issue. It looks like it works https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bdbklb

Comment: Probably this issue is for the exact material version you have installed. What is your version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the [ChangeDetectionStrategy Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy) for

#### OnPush

> Use the CheckOnce strategy, meaning that automatic change detection is
> deactivated until reactivated by setting the strategy to Default
> (CheckAlways). Change detection can still be explicitly invoked. This
> strategy applies to all child directives and cannot be overridden.

Further we can look at the [Using OnPush Docs](https://angular.io/guide/change-detection-skipping-subtrees#using-onpush)

> OnPush change detection instructs Angular to run change detection for
> a component subtree only when:
>
> - The root component of the subtree receives new inputs as the result of a template binding. Angular compares the current and past value of
>   the input with ==
> - Angular handles an event (for example using event binding, output binding, or @HostListener ) in the subtree's root component or any of
>   its children whether they are using OnPush change detection or not.

**So in your scenario, there is no change of `@Input` nor hostlisteners being triggered in your code, so change detection has not detected the changes**

#### When to use Change detection strategy - On Push

1. When the performance of the component is impact when normal change detection is set, it could be due to large number of listeners, or heavy front end code tied to change detection.
2. When you are sure that the component is pretty basic and all scenarios can be handled without the full fledged change detection, meaning that same can be achieved by on push itself ( Better overall application performance, since few components wont have change detection which increases memory of browser for more important tasks! )

#### How to trigger manual Change detection - [Change Detector Ref Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#changedetectorref)

We can import the change detector ref and call the methods.

- [markForCheck()](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#markforcheck)
- [detectChanges()](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectchanges)

---

So the fix for your issue might be triggering change detection manually using `markForCheck()` or `detectChanges()`. Since we want to run change detection on tab change we use the mat tab event [selectedTabChange](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTab)

ts

```
...
constructor(
    ...
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    ...) {}

selectedTabChange() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    // or
    // this.cdr.markForCheck();
}
```

html

```
...
<mat-tab-group color="accent" (selectedTabChange)="selectedTabChange($event)">
    ...
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. i read the docs, of course, but you explained it very clearly. it became much clearer to me and now I can read again, already understanding, and watch a video on this topic. Thank you again!